# What is the difference between az acr repository delete and untag commands?

Tags: image, docker, manifest, azure-container-registry

I am trying to write a script to clean up the Azure container registry. The commands I used for this purpose are:

```
# Remove images with unwanted tags
az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $imageName --yes

# Remove dangling images
az acr repository show-manifests --name $AzureRegistryName --repository $RepositoryName --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv `
   | %{ az acr repository delete --name $AzureRegistryName --image $RepositoryName@$_ --yes }
```

`imagename`  refers to a combination of `repository:unwantedtag` .

As specified above, I am using `az acr repository delete` command. This deletes the manifest referenced by `imagename` and all other tags referencing the same manifest.

If I have the same image with two different tags, namely `test:100` and `test:101`, then both will have same manifest. For cleanup purpose, I want to keep only one of them. If i delete one image `test:100`, then removing the manifest will delete `test:101` also. This is not desirable.

The other thing is if I want to delete both the tags during the cleanup, after deleting  `test:100` first, when I attempt to delete `test:101`, it will return an error:

```
az : ERROR: Error: manifest unknown.
```

Even if it will not stop the script from executing further, the error is annoying. Both the tags are removed also.

So basically, what I need is a solution for this problem.
Will using `az acr repository untag` command instead of `delete` resolve this issue? What if I untag the images with unwanted tags and then run a command to remove dangling manifests?

How the `delete` and `untag` commands differ in this perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`az acr repository delete` command deletes an image by tag. All layers unique to the image, and any other tags associated with the image are deleted.

`az acr repository untag` command deletes the tag. No space is freed when you untag an image because its manifest and layer data remain in the registry. Only the tag reference itself is deleted.

The actual method I needed was first untagging the images and then remove the dangling manifests.

Comment: You could perhaps rely on Azure Retention policy for ACRs to remove the dangling manifests when they are dangling for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Azure retention policy is available in ACR premium tier only.